# Python3 How to handle special characters returned in output of subprocess.run?

Tags: python

The code I am running looks something like this

```
o=subprocess.run( ['ls -1 pathtosomedir/'+prefix+'*'],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print('details:',o.stdout)
```

If the file returned has brackets for example test(1).csv

then output is

details:test(1).csv

**/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected**

Why does it seem to be trying to parse the output? And whats the right way to handle these cases? Thanks!

(I am using python 3.6.9)

EDIT: Turned out the o.stdout was being passed to subsequent subprocess.run. And if the o.stdout contained brackets it need to be escaped as mentioned in the answer. So closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stdout` and `print` statement should not be parsing the output. The issue is likely on the first line.

Is there a parenthesis or special character in the `prefix` variable?
For example:

```
o=subprocess.run(['ls' + ' test(1)'])
```

will give you the exact error that you specified

`/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token (`

because you need to escape the parentheses with a backslash like so :

```
o=subprocess.run(['ls' + ' test\(1\)'])
```

Comment: The prefix has just numbers...so not sure whats going on. Maybe something to do with the * and when its being expanded. I am not sure maybe python is trying to expand it instead of the shell...

Comment: Hey thanks your comment made me find the issue! It was coming from a subsequent subprocess.run that used o.stdout that contained the brackets and those brackets needed to be escaped!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!